# Why priority queue gives such a result?

Tags: priority-queue

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
    for(int i = 10; i>0; i--){
        queue.offer(i);
    }
    System.out.println(queue);
}
```

this code gives
[1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 9, 6, 10, 7, 8]

why? 
I expected it to be numbers in ascending order, due to natural ordering of Integer class.

Comment: A priority queue is not necessarily an ordered list. The simplest implementation would be a heap.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927213/java-priority-queue

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to print the queue. you need to peek and pull it and it will be sorted. The toString() method is not ordered but the queue is.